# Powershell: How To Extract Binary File Attributes From Directory Listing

Tags: powershell, datetime-format

In PowerShell, I can get a nice list of files in descending sorted order using a filter:

```
$tt = gci -Path \\Munis2\musys_read\export_test\* -Include "ARLMA_*.csv" | sort LastWriteTime -Descending

PS H:\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts\ProductionScripts\Munis> $tt


    Directory: \\Munis2\musys_read\export_test


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        03/04/2022   3:09 AM       25545520 ARLMA_20220304030027.csv
.
.
.
```

Then, I can get just the name of the file for the purposes of transferring that file to an FTP site.

```
PS H:\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts\ProductionScripts\Munis> $tt[0].Name
ARLMA_20220304030027.csv
```

How can I parse $tt[0].LastWriteTime

```
PS H:\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts\ProductionScripts\Munis> $tt[0].LastWriteTime

Friday, March 4, 2022 3:09:14 AM
```

into something that looks like yymmddhhmmss, or is there a way to get the binary time of the file the last time it was accessed?

Comment: You can use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2) to output the `LastWriteTime` in whatever format you like. ;-)

Comment: Which properties of the files are you looking to get, besides the "formatted" `LastWriteTime` ?

Comment: Basically, if I get the files binary last write and turn today's date into binary, I can compare the vales.

Comment: For this comparison you don't need to reformat something. PowerShell is easily able to compare properties of type [DateTime]. You may explain a little more detailed what you actually want to do - not the way you think you need to go to achieve this. There might be an easier way. ;-)

Comment: `(Get-Date)` (same as `[datetime]::Now`) would give you today's date and being a DateTime object, just like a file's `.LastWriteTime`, `.LastAccessTime` etc.  property they are mutually comparable. To format a datetime object simply use its `.ToString()` method like `$fileobject.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss")`

Answer (score 0):

The ToString() method can be used to format the date into a string. Are you sure that a two digit year is appropriate?

```
$DateResult = (Get-ChildItem -Path \\Munis2\musys_read\export_test\* -Include "ARLMA_*.csv" |
    Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 1).LastWriteTime.ToString('yyMMddHHmmss')
```